# Error using Scrollview - Swift

Tags: swift, loops, uiscrollview

[image: This are my codes, looking for a possible solution to the error]

```
//
// ViewController.swift
// Login
//
// Created by MAC on 14/07/2016.
// Copyright 2016 VerseCom. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollview: UIScrollView!

    let WIDTH : CGFloat = 320
    let HIEGHT : CGFloat = 568

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var i in 1..4 {
            let img = UIImage(named: "/(i)")
            let imgview = UIImageView(image: img)
            self.scrollview.addSubview(imgview)

        }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Odusina Timilehin, welcome to stackoverflow, here is guide to how to to ask a question on stackoverflow : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: please try code in my answer below @Odusina Timilehin

Comment: If you find my or any answer correct for you please accept it with this way : http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235.

Comment: Next time, please post your code *and* error messages **directly as text**.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to loop through few times with for-In loops but you use it this way in your code :

```
var i in 1...4 {
 ...
}
```

here is how you should use it :

You use the for-in loop to iterate over a sequence, such as ranges of numbers, items in an array, or characters in a string.

This example prints the first few entries in the five-times table:

```
for index in 1...5 {
    print("\(index) times 5 is \(index * 5)")
}

// 1 times 5 is 5
// 2 times 5 is 10
// 3 times 5 is 15
// 4 times 5 is 20
// 5 times 5 is 25
```

another example :

```
let base = 3
let power = 10
var answer = 1
for _ in 1...power {
    answer *= base
}
print("\(base) to the power of \(power) is \(answer)")
// Prints "3 to the power of 10 is 59049"
```

And another :

```
let names = ["Anna", "Alex", "Brian", "Jack"]
for name in names {
    print("Hello, \(name)!")
}
// Hello, Anna!
// Hello, Alex!
// Hello, Brian!
// Hello, Jack!
```

and another :

```
let numberOfLegs = ["spider": 8, "ant": 6, "cat": 4]
for (animalName, legCount) in numberOfLegs {
    print("\(animalName)s have \(legCount) legs")
}
// ants have 6 legs
// cats have 4 legs
// spiders have 8 legs
```

[From Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html)

Comment: your welcome, please accept my answer like this : http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235